# Guess , What am I?

Tags: word

If you look you cannot see me. And if you see me you cannot see anything else. I can make anything you want happen, but later everything goes back to normal. What am I?

Comment: "The screen inside an Oculus Rift" seems to fit the bill :)

Comment: ^ That comment came automatically, but it's DEFINITELY a duplicate. Sorry Saurabh! :-)

Comment: yeah , but i don't know that it's already there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think it is:

> Imagination

If you look you cannot see me

> If you just normally look at your surrounding

if you see me you cannot see anything else

> if you imagine you'll be out of your sight

I can make anything you want happen

> you can imagine anything( like being part of avengers :D )

but later everything goes back to normal

> if you stop imagining, you bring back to reality

Answer (score 3):

It can be a

> Dream

If you look, you cannot see me,.

> You need to close Eyes to see dream

And if you see me you cannot see anything else

> While dreaming you can't see anything else as your eyes are closed.

I can make anything you want happen

> In dream you can be what you want.

but later everything goes back to normal.

> After you wake up, all will be back to normal.

Comment: I can see dream while my eyes is open :p "day dreaming" :D

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** HA! @Himanshu beat me by a minute! :D

According to me, the answer is:

> Dream

**Explanation:**

If you look you cannot see me:

> You can't see a dream unless you are sleeping!

if you see me you cannot see anything else

> While dreaming you can't see anything else.

I can make anything you want happen

> We all know how Lucid dreaming works. You can just be anyone and do anything.

But later everything goes back to normal

> As soon as you wake up, you are back to normal life.

Comment: type fast next time, hahaha :p

Comment: Took me time to find out about the spoiler tag! :(